# URL-Mapping in Web.XML Not Being Read

Tags: servlets, web-applications

I updated an app. And to make a long story short, the server keeps looking at the old URL-Pattern for some unknown reason.  It used to be 'calculate' and after I have changed it to 'profilesrvlt' it's still 'calculate'!  And so, I get a "HTTP Status 404 - Not Found, Message The requested resource [/ProfileServlet/calculate] is not available" error.

The code's right here,
web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<web-app 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_4_0.xsd" 
id="WebApp_ID" 
version="4.0">

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>ProfileSLT</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>ProfileServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>ProfileSLT</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/profilesrvlt</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Log in to your profile</title>
<style>
.wrapper{
    width: 40%;
    border: 1px solid #666;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 20px;
    
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wrapper">
    <h1>Profile page</h1>
    <!-- Give servlet name -->
    <form action="ProfileSLT" method="post">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="profileLogIn">Log in</a></td><td> | </td>
            <td><a href="profileLogOut">Log out</a></td><td> | </td>
            <td><a href="myProfile">Profile</a></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>User name: </td>
            <td><input type="text" name="user_name" placeholder="Name" /></td>
            <td>Password</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="user_password" placeholder="Password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2">
                <input type="submit" value="Log On "/>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Anybody know how I may fix this?

EDIT: I noticed that if I enter the correct URL manually, I get the following error:

HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error

Message Error instantiating servlet class [ProfileServlet]
Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.

SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet [ProfileServlet]
java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: ProfileServlet has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 60.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0 (unable to load class [ProfileServlet])

Comment: Something I did caused it to "refresh" or something and now I'm getting "The requested resource [/ProfileServlet/ProfileSLT] is not available".  That's probably what it is because if I make a change it takes it some time to "see" it.

Comment: And, yes, I am restarting the server, Apache Tomcat 10.